# Issues with Nokogiri on Mac

Tags: nokogiri, libxml2, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying to parse an OFX file from the ofx gem, which works fine in Ubuntu but
gives me an error on Mac OS.

I am using RVM. Here are the details:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553)

rails -v
2.3.11

gem -v
1.6.2

* gem list *
nokogiri (1.5.0, 1.4.6)
ofx (0.3.1) 

-- control frame ----------
c:0065 p:---- s:0320 b:0320 l:000319 d:000319 CFUNC  :root
c:0064 p:0052 s:0317 b:0317 l:000316 d:000316 METHOD /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:100
c:0063 p:0030 s:0311 b:0309 l:000308 d:000308 METHOD /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ofx-0.3.1/lib/ofx/parser/ofx102.rb:50
c:0062 p:0025 s:0306 b:0306 l:000305 d:000305 METHOD /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ofx-0.3.1/lib/ofx/parser/ofx102.rb:26
c:0061 p:0302 s:0303 b:0303 l:000302 d:000302 METHOD /Users/abc/Code/RubyUpgrade/app/models/check_clear.rb:38
c:0060 p:---- s:0297 b:0297 l:000296 d:000296 FINISH
c:0059 p:---- s:0295 b:0295 l:000294 d:000294 CFUNC  :new
c:0058 p:0050 s:0289 b:0289 l:001898 d:000288 BLOCK  /Users/abc/Code/RubyUpgrade/app/controllers/checks_controller.rb:116
c:0057 p:0182 s:0287 b:0287 l:000286 d:000286 METHOD /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_state
```

Comment: This doesn't do us any good unless you provide sample code and data that recreates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me was to remove the RVM libiconv package as per instructions here:

https://rvm.io/packages/iconv/